# xmlTreeParse and html content

Tags: r, web-scraping

I can't get (web scrape) html tree content with R function xmlTreeParse - I mean common page with products.

I get library Rcurl and XML.

```
myurln3<-"www.amazon.com/s?k=router+hand+plane+cheap&i=arts-crafts-intl-ship&ref=nb_sb_noss"
html_page<-xmlTreeParse(myurln3, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

> Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:
> 'www.amazon.com/s?k=router+hand+plane+cheap&i=arts-crafts-intl-ship&ref=nb_sb_noss'

I expect to scrape page and get full html structure.

Comment: Use `readLines`: `xmlTreeParse(readLines(myurln3))`

Comment: Unfortunately: Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'www.amazon.com/s?k=router+hand+plane+cheap&i=arts-crafts-intl-ship&ref=nb_sb_noss': No such file or directory

Comment: Try `xmlParse` instead of `xmlTreeParse`.

Comment: The same warning message. When I load library XML I got: pakiet ‘XML’ został zbudowany w wersji R 3.5.3 (Eng: XML package is in R 3.5.3 version) and I use RStudio 1.1.463. The same message with Rcurl.

Answer (score 0):

I back after some other projects to web scraping with R and still with problems.

```
> library(XML)

Warning message:
XML package is in R 3.5.3 version 

> my_url99 <- "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Dell+laptop+windows+10&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"
> html_page99 <- htmlTreeParse(my_url99, useInternalNode=TRUE)

Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Dell+laptop+windows+10&ref=nb_sb_noss_2' 

> head(html_page99)

Error in `[.XMLInternalDocument`(x, seq_len(n)) : 
  No method for subsetting an XMLInternalDocument with integer

> html_page99

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Dell+laptop+windows+10&amp;ref=nb_sb_noss_2</p></body></html>
```

But I need to scrape above page with full content = I mean content with $ sign on the left (fmaybe that's not the best direct description) and all the tags.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add this to it or post a new question.

Comment: Ok, Admin please finish this question.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, there is an [edit] link in the bottom left corner so you can edit it by yourself

Comment: See also [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)